# Is there an equivalent function of R's eacf in python?

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I've read some words sounds like `eacf` is quite good for order dermination of ARIMA.
I wonder if there is a equivalent function in Python, or a bettery solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of looking for `eacf` is to get the parameters automatically.
Finally I find [auto_arima](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html), the result probably is not perfect, but a rough range of params can be got.

Here is how Docs introduce itself

> `pmdarima` bring's R's beloved `auto.arima` to Python, making an even stronger case for why you don't need R for data science. `pmdarima` is 100% Python+Cython and does not leverage any R code, but is implemented in a powerful, yet easy-to-use set of functions & classes that will be familiar to scikit-learn users.